# CubeSat's ConOps implementation as a FSM with thread management

Tags: cubesat, software

Can anyone shed light on this for me: How would you implement a Concept of Operations of a CubeSat as a Finite State Machine that manages each thread's priority?

Thank you !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question asks us to write multiple books. There are many, many books and papers on writing / implementing concepts of operations, on writing / implementing a finite state machine, on failure management (your ConOps had better cover this), on realtime computing, on multithreaded computing, on prioritization, and even on traitorous generals. (When you introduce multiple threads you introduce the possibility that one of those threads will be traitorous. This is the Byzantine Generals Problem, and your ConOps might need to cover this as well.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is overly broad.